# Не могу разобраться с кодом для VK.api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не могу разобраться с добавлением клавиатуры к боту вконтакте, пробовал разные способы из интернета в итоге остановился на этом но он тоже на работает. Выдает ошибку

```
keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard,ensure.asii=False).encode('utf-8')
                              ^
```

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import requests
import json
def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message})
def get_button(lable, color, payload=""):
    return {
        "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "payload":json.dumps(payload),
            "label":lable
            },
        "color": color
    }
keyboard = {
    "one_time" : False,
    "buttons" : [
        [
            get_button("Кноп1",color="positive"),
            get_button("Кноп2",color="negative"),
            get_button("Кноп3",color="primary"),
            get_button("Кноп4",color="default")
        ]
        ]
    }
keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard,ensure.asii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = sr(keyboard.decode('utf-8')  )    
        
            

token = "....."


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)


longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


for event in longpoll.listen():

    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
    
       
        if event.to_me:
        
          
            request = event.text
            
          
            if request == "привет":
                 write_msg(event.user_id, "Хай", "keyboard"=keyboard)
```

Comment: Запятую поставьте после `}` перед `"color": color`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: возникла еще одна ошибка, не поможете, в json не разбираюсь от слова совсем

Comment: `keyboard= { "one_time" = False,` должно быть  `keyboard= { "one_time" : False,` Будьте внимательнее к коду, похоже основная проблема в опечатках и невнимательности

Comment: понял, спасибо но код все равно отказывается работать, сколько бы я ни старался, можете пожалуйста подсказать как эту клавиатуру заставить вывеститись на экран, в самой последней строчке выдает ошибку, я пробовал множество вариантов но ничего не помогло(